# Php cannot use object stdClass as array

Tags: php, json, object

Derp.
Getting 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'

I dunno what I'm doing wrong here:

```
foreach ($json->result->items[$key]->attributes->attribute as $attrib => $val) 
{
    if($json->result->items[$key]->attributes->attribute[$attrib]->name == 'cannot_trade')
    {
        $notrade=1;
        echo 'Item ' . $key . ' is not tradeable' . $br;
    }
}
```

And here's the data:

```
[attributes] => stdClass Object
(
  [attribute] => Array
  (
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
      [name] => custom employee number
      [class] => set_employee_number
      [value] => 0
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
      [name] => cannot trade
      [class] => cannot_trade
      [value] => 1
    )
  )
)
```

Essentially, I'm trying to test to see if the 'attribute' array has the cannot_trade thingy.
Sometimes, the parent object doesn't have an 'attributes' object

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! If your problem is solved, please post the solution also, so that others may benefit.

Comment: which access is causing the error?

Answer (score 9):

You can parse your JSON as an array if you want:

```
// These both give you an array:
$json = json_decode($whatever, true);
$json = (array) json_decode($whatever);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
if($val->name == 'cannot_trade')
{
    $notrade=1;
    echo 'Item ' . $key . ' is not tradeable' . $br;
}
```

If it still doesn't works, try adding

```
var_dump($val);
```

in the loop, to check what it really contains.